# Org-mode tables: How to insert result of a system command?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Org-mode I would like to insert the result of a Unix command in a field. For instance, consider I have the following table:

```
| /        |
| /bin     |
| /usr/bin |
| /lib     |
| /usr/lib |
```

I would like to insert a second column such as

```
$2 = <result of `du -sh $1` >
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an approximation to your problem:

```
#+TBLNAME: pepe
| /tmp      |
| /usr/info |

#+begin_src sh :var tt=pepe
du -sh $tt
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 4.0K | /tmp      |
| 532K | /usr/info |
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your table snippet and pressed `C-c C-c`, the table isn't updated and I only get the msg `Local setup has been refreshed'. How can I execute the formula?

Comment: This is actual cut/paste from my test. `C-c C-c` should be done over the source block (not over the table). And you must have `sh` added to `org-babel-load-languages` setting.

Comment: It worked with Org-mode version 7.8.11, but I cannot seem to add `sh` to `org-babel-load-languages` on Org-mode 6.33x version (old version I have at work). Any chance you know how to do this on older versions?